# React this.setState in regular method notation

Tags: reactjs

I am a React newbie, and am working on examples from [Adam Freeman's book](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484244500).

I am starting with simple event handling and am unable to figure out why the regular-looking version of handleClick() below does not work. The method using the arrow notation (from the book) works as expected, but I am trying to translate it to the standard method notation, and am unable to figure out what is missing.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  count: 4
 }
}

isEven(val) { return val % 2 === 0 ? "Even" : "Odd"; }

// the following works
//handleClick = () => this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });

// this gives an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
handleClick() {
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
}

render = () =>
<h4>
  <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me!</button>
  Number of items: {this.isEven(this.state.count)}
</h4>
}
```

What changes are needed for handleclick() to work?

Comment: You need to bind it in constructor as `this.handleClick =  this.handleClick.bind(this)`;

Comment: I would use arrow function when declare the click function: `handleClick = () => this.setState({})`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind `this` using one of the below,

In Constructor,

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  count: 4
 }
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

Or you can directly bind `this` as,

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Click me!</button>
```

Or simply using `fat arrow` syntax,

```
<button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Click me!</button>
```

[Ref](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56)

Comment: Thanks very much, don't quite understand yet how this works. but it works. Probably some more experience will help.